# Using a helper function in a template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I wrote a `full_name(user)` helper function and would like to use it in the template.

I tried using `<%= full_name(@current_user) %>` in the template but get an `undefined function full_name` error. How can I use this function in a template?

**web/views/user_helpers.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.UserHelpers do
  alias MyApp.User

  def full_name(%User{first_name: first_name,
                      last_name: last_name,
                      honorific_prefix: honorific_prefix,
                      honorific_suffix: honorific_suffix}) do
    [honorific_prefix, first_name, last_name, honorific_suffix]
    |> Enum.reject(&(&1 == ""))
    |> Enum.join(" ")
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The helpers aren't special in any way, they are just modules containing functions. You need to either use the full name of the function (including the module name):

```
<%= MyApp.UserHelpers.full_name(@current_user) %>
```

Or import it into the view (since templates are compiled into the view, the function will be available in the scope of the template):

```
MyApp.UserView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view
  import MyApp.UserHelpers
  ...
end
```

Then you can use:

```
<%= full_name(@current_user) %>
```